# Ionic build failed: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: angular, gradle, ionic-framework, build.gradle

Unable to build `ionic cordova build android --prod`
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

[image: Refference: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.]

build.gradle(app)

> /*
> Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
> or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
> distributed with this work for additional information
> regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
> to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
> "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
> with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
>
> ```
>          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
>
>        Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
>        software distributed under the License is distributed on an
>        "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
>        KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
>        specific language governing permissions and limitations
>        under the License.
> */
>
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>
> if (cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference('GradlePluginKotlinEnabled', 'false').toBoolean()) {
>     apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
>     apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
> }
>
> buildscript {
>     apply from: '../CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
>
>     if(cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference('GradlePluginKotlinEnabled', 'false').toBoolean()) {
>         String defaultGradlePluginKotlinVersion = kotlin_version
>
>         /**
>          * Fetches the user's defined Kotlin Version from config.xml.
>          * If the version is not set or invalid, it will default to the ${defaultGradlePluginKotlinVersion}
>          */
>         String gradlePluginKotlinVersion = cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference('GradlePluginKotlinVersion',
> ```
>
> defaultGradlePluginKotlinVersion)
> if(!cdvHelpers.isVersionValid(gradlePluginKotlinVersion)) {
> println("The defined Kotlin version (${gradlePluginKotlinVersion}) does not appear to be a valid version.
> Falling back to version: ${defaultGradlePluginKotlinVersion}.")
> gradlePluginKotlinVersion = defaultGradlePluginKotlinVersion
> }
>
> ```
>         // Change the version to be used.
>         ext.kotlin_version = gradlePluginKotlinVersion
>     }
>
>     apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
>     repositories repos
>
>     dependencies {
>         apply from: '../CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
>
>         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
>
>         if (cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference('GradlePluginKotlinEnabled',
> ```
>
> 'false').toBoolean()) {
> classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
> }
>
> ```
>         if(cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference('GradlePluginGoogleServicesEnabled',
> ```
>
> 'false').toBoolean()) {
> String defaultGradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion = '4.2.0'
>
> ```
>             /**
>              * Fetches the user's defined Google Services Plugin Version from config.xml.
>              * If the version is not set or invalid, it will default to the ${defaultGradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion}
>              */
>             String gradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion = cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference('GradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion',
> ```
>
> defaultGradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion)
> if(!cdvHelpers.isVersionValid(gradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion)) {
> println("The defined Google Services plugin version (${gradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion}) does not appear to be a
> valid version. Falling back to version:
> ${defaultGradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion}.")
> gradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion = defaultGradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion
> }
>
> ```
>             // Create the Google Services classpath and set it.
>             String gradlePluginGoogleServicesClassPath = "com.google.gms:google-services:${gradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion}"
>             println "Adding classpath: ${gradlePluginGoogleServicesClassPath}"
>             classpath gradlePluginGoogleServicesClassPath
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> // Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
> allprojects {
>     apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
>     repositories repos
> }
>
> task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
>     gradleVersion = '6.5'
> }
>
> // Configuration properties. Set these via environment variables, build-extras.gradle, or gradle.properties.
> // Refer to: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html
> ext {
>     apply from: '../CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
>
>     // The value for android.compileSdkVersion.
>     if (!project.hasProperty('cdvCompileSdkVersion')) {
>         cdvCompileSdkVersion = null;
>     }
>     // The value for android.buildToolsVersion.
>     if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildToolsVersion')) {
>         cdvBuildToolsVersion = null;
>     }
>     // Sets the versionCode to the given value.
>     if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
>         cdvVersionCode = null
>     }
>     // Sets the minSdkVersion to the given value.
>     if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMinSdkVersion')) {
>         cdvMinSdkVersion = null
>     }
>     // Sets the maxSdkVersion to the given value.
>     if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMaxSdkVersion')) {
>         cdvMaxSdkVersion = null
>     }
>     // The value for android.targetSdkVersion.
>     if (!project.hasProperty('cdvTargetSdkVersion')) {
>         cdvTargetSdkVersion = null;
>     }
>     // Whether to build architecture-specific APKs.
>     if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
>         cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
>     }
>     // Whether to append a 0 "abi digit" to versionCode when only a single APK is build
>     if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit')) {
>         cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit = null
>     }
>     // .properties files to use for release signing.
>     if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
>         cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
>     }
>     // .properties files to use for debug signing.
>     if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
>         cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
>     }
>     // Set by build.js script.
>     if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
>         cdvBuildArch = null
>     }
>
>     // Plugin gradle extensions can append to this to have code run at the end.
>     cdvPluginPostBuildExtras = []
> }
>
> // PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS START
> apply from: "../cordova-android-support-gradle-release/bookmi-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle"
> apply from: "../cordova-plugin-braintree/bookmi-build-extras.gradle"
> apply from: "../cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/bookmi-FCMPlugin.gradle"
> // PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END
>
> def hasBuildExtras1 = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
> if (hasBuildExtras1) {
>     apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
> }
>
> def hasBuildExtras2 = file('../build-extras.gradle').exists()
> if (hasBuildExtras2) {
>     apply from: '../build-extras.gradle'
> }
>
> // Set property defaults after extension .gradle files.
> ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion = cdvCompileSdkVersion == null ? (
>     defaultCompileSdkVersion == null
>         ? privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
>         : defaultCompileSdkVersion
> ) : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvCompileSdkVersion);
>
> if (ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion == null) {
>     ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
>     //ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = project.ext.defaultBuildToolsVersion
> }
> if (ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('../debug-signing.properties').exists()) {
>     ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = '../debug-signing.properties'
> }
> if (ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('../release-signing.properties').exists()) {
>     ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = '../release-signing.properties'
> }
>
> // Cast to appropriate types.
> ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks = cdvBuildMultipleApks == null ? false : cdvBuildMultipleApks.toBoolean();
> ext.cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit = cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit == null ? false : cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit.toBoolean();
>
> // minSdkVersion, maxSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion
> ext.cdvMinSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion == null ? defaultMinSdkVersion : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
> if (cdvMaxSdkVersion != null) {
>     ext.cdvMaxSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt('' + cdvMaxSdkVersion)
> }
> ext.cdvTargetSdkVersion = cdvTargetSdkVersion == null ? defaultTargetSdkVersion  : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvTargetSdkVersion)
>
> ext.cdvVersionCode = cdvVersionCode == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvVersionCode)
>
> def computeBuildTargetName(debugBuild) {
>     def ret = 'assemble'
>     if (cdvBuildMultipleApks && cdvBuildArch) {
>         def arch = cdvBuildArch == 'arm' ? 'armv7' : cdvBuildArch
>         ret += '' + arch.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + arch.substring(1);
>     }
>     return ret + (debugBuild ? 'Debug' : 'Release')
> }
>
> // Make cdvBuild a task that depends on the debug/arch-sepecific task.
> task cdvBuildDebug
> cdvBuildDebug.dependsOn {
>     return computeBuildTargetName(true)
> }
>
> task cdvBuildRelease
> cdvBuildRelease.dependsOn {
>     return computeBuildTargetName(false)
> }
>
> task cdvPrintProps {
>     doLast {
>         println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
>         println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
>         println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
>         println('cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit=' + cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit)
>         println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
>         println('cdvMaxSdkVersion=' + cdvMaxSdkVersion)
>         println('cdvTargetSdkVersion=' + cdvTargetSdkVersion)
>         println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
>         println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
>         println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
>         println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
>         println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
>         android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
>             println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> android {
>     defaultConfig {
>         versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
>         applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")
>
>         if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
>             minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
>         }
>
>         if (cdvMaxSdkVersion != null) {
>             maxSdkVersion cdvMaxSdkVersion
>         }
>
>         if(cdvTargetSdkVersion != null) {
>             targetSdkVersion cdvTargetSdkVersion
>         }
>     }
>
>     lintOptions {
>       abortOnError false;
>     }
>
>     compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
>     buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion
>
>     // This code exists for Crosswalk and other Native APIs.
>     // By default, we multiply the existing version code in the
>     // Android Manifest by 10 and add a number for each architecture.
>     // If you are not using Crosswalk or SQLite, you can
>     // ignore this chunk of code, and your version codes will be respected.
>
>     if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
>         flavorDimensions "default"
>
>         productFlavors {
>             armeabi {
>                 versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 1
>                 ndk {
>                     abiFilters = ["armeabi"]
>                 }
>             }
>             armv7 {
>                 versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 2
>                 ndk {
>                     abiFilters = ["armeabi-v7a"]
>                 }
>             }
>             arm64 {
>                 versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 3
>                 ndk {
>                     abiFilters = ["arm64-v8a"]
>                 }
>             }
>             x86 {
>                 versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 4
>                 ndk {
>                     abiFilters = ["x86"]
>                 }
>             }
>             x86_64 {
>                 versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 5
>                 ndk {
>                     abiFilters = ["x86_64"]
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     } else if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit)) {
>         // This provides compatibility to the default logic for versionCode before cordova-android 5.2.0
>         defaultConfig {
>             versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10
>         }
>     }
>
>     compileOptions {
>         sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
>         targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
>     }
>
>     if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
>         signingConfigs {
>             release {
>                 // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
>                 keyAlias = ""
>                 keyPassword = "__unset" // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task
> ```
>
> graph.
> storeFile = null
> storePassword = "__unset"
> }
> }
> buildTypes {
> release {
> signingConfig signingConfigs.release
> }
> }
> addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
> }
>
> ```
>     if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
>         addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
>     }
>
>     sourceSets {
>         main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
>     }
> }
>
> /*
>  * WARNING: Cordova Lib and platform scripts do management inside of this code here,
>  * if you are adding the dependencies manually, do so outside the comments, otherwise
>  * the Cordova tools will overwrite them
>  */
>
>
> dependencies {
>     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
>
>     if (cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference('GradlePluginKotlinEnabled',
> ```
>
> 'false').toBoolean()) {
> implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
> }
>
> ```
>     // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
>     implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
>     implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"
>     implementation "com.stripe:stripe-android:4.1.2"
>     // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
> }
>
> def promptForReleaseKeyPassword() {
>     if (!cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
>         return;
>     }
>     if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword)) {
>         android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key store password: ')
>     }
>     if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword)) {
>         android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key password: ');
>     }
> }
>
> gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
>     taskGraph.getAllTasks().each() { task ->
>       if(['validateReleaseSigning', 'validateSigningRelease', 'validateSigningArmv7Release',
> ```
>
> 'validateSigningX76Release'].contains(task.name)) {
> promptForReleaseKeyPassword()
> }
> }
> }
>
> ```
> def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
>     def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
>     def props = new Properties()
>     propsFile.withReader { reader ->
>         props.load(reader)
>     }
>
>     def storeFile = new File(props.get('key.store') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'storeFile'))
>     if (!storeFile.isAbsolute()) {
>         storeFile = RelativePath.parse(true, storeFile.toString()).getFile(propsFile.getParentFile())
>     }
>     if (!storeFile.exists()) {
>         throw new FileNotFoundException('Keystore file does not exist: ' + storeFile.getAbsolutePath())
>     }
>     signingConfig.keyAlias = props.get('key.alias') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'keyAlias')
>     signingConfig.keyPassword = props.get('keyPassword', props.get('key.alias.password', signingConfig.keyPassword))
>     signingConfig.storeFile = storeFile
>     signingConfig.storePassword = props.get('storePassword', props.get('key.store.password', signingConfig.storePassword))
>     def storeType = props.get('storeType', props.get('key.store.type', ''))
>     if (!storeType) {
>         def filename = storeFile.getName().toLowerCase();
>         if (filename.endsWith('.p12') || filename.endsWith('.pfx')) {
>             storeType = 'pkcs12'
>         } else {
>             storeType = signingConfig.storeType // "jks"
>         }
>     }
>     signingConfig.storeType = storeType
> }
>
> for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
>     func()
> }
>
> // This can be defined within build-extras.gradle as:
> //     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
> if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
>     postBuildExtras()
> }
>
> if (cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference('GradlePluginGoogleServicesEnabled',
> ```
>
> 'false').toBoolean()) {
> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
> }

Comment: Can you also share the content of `variables.gradle` and `build.gradle`?

Comment: edited my quesion

Comment: There are two `build.gradle` files. One's inside android/app and one's outside. In the outside file, check  if there are lines specific sdk version like this: `defaultMinSdkVersion=22;defaultTargetSdkVersion=29; defaultCompileSdkVersion=29`

Comment: yes i have found it.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you fix that?

Comment: @FernandoAureliano try removing plugins folder and all the node_packages and ionic cordova platform rm android
then update cordova and then install everything again

Answer (score 0):

Just add

`<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="22" />`

in the config.xml and remove android platform

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

and after that try to recreate the platform and everything should work like normal

Comment: i have tried this trick no luck :(

Comment: @Wiki When you re-create `ionic cordova platform add android`, did it show any errors ?

Comment: yes the same error menioned in question

Comment: Can you share your config.xml file, and if you create a new empty project do you get the error?